# Can players create custom totems?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse

Is it possible to create a custom totem? Or should the pack just choose a existing totem from the books and then spend points in Totem Background to improve it?

If the players can create a custom totem, how can they do it? There is no point in the Background description that serves to improve Abilities rolls, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no explicit mechanical description for this. It's up to GM's judgement to decide what should be the background cost, provided boons and required bans, according to the party's expectations and the spirit's flavor.

Comment: Well, for Werewoves, anyway. Mages have their own rules for Totems that are completely unrelated to the Werewolf rules and which do allow for custom Totems.

Answer (score 1):

### Making a totem your own!

There are premade totems in about every Werewolf book that isn't just an adventure. Usually, there's at least one, often more. Finding one with benefits you like should be possible, or you play a little switcheroo with the benefits of a totem. Then you can "reskin" the stat block and swap names and bans to fit your group better.

### Totem Construction Kit?

The closest you come to a totem construction kit is list of totem powers that can be bought by the pooled "Totem" background, and which can be applied to the (modified/reskinned) totem. They can be found in the core book under the description of Totem.<sup>1</sup>

Note that this table isn't in the core book for Revised edition.<sup>2.</sup>

### Notes

1. W20 Core, p.140.
   Werewolf: The Apocalypse, 2nd Edition, p.113.
   Werewolf: The Apocalypse, 1st Edition, p.134.
2. Werewolf: The Apocalypse, Revised Edition, pp.293.